# Identical public/private ip address by host name

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I host my `backbone + require + underscore .js`  website on a public server for the clients browse and also in local server of my company for employees.

People outside can access to my website by public ip address or domain name; otherwise, employees in local network could access by private ip address.

I possibly get host name which user type in url such as `www.mydomain.com`, `http://114.130.180.248` (just example public ip), `http://184.150.10.26` (private ip) BY using `jquery`.

**What I want to do is** : Test whether the user access my website using `public ip/domain name` or `private ip(local network)` so if the user is a private user, I will redirect to those private path, for the same purpose, if the users access by public uri, I would redirect to public server.

**Why I want to do that** : because I have registered path of images, webservices, reports in variable of my backbone web config as `constants` as example :

```
//private host
MySite.WebServiceHost = "184.150.10.23";
MySite.WebsiteHost = "184.150.10.26";
MySite.PathImage = "184.150.10.25";
MySite.ReportingHost = "184.150.10.24";

//public host
MySite.WebServiceHost = "114.130.180.245";
MySite.WebsiteHost = "114.130.180.248";
MySite.PathImage = "114.130.180.246";
MySite.ReportingHost = "1114.130.180.247";
```

**Note** : I don't want to validate ip address by ranges (`10.0.0.0` – `10.255.255.255`, `172.16.0.0` – `172.31.255.255`, `192.168.0.0` – `192.168.255.255`) ? Because private ip address of us is not permanently use, it is changed due to some other policies of our organization, so it could be the other ranges beside the range I mentioned above (could be 185.xxx.xxx.xxx or something else).

Again, any ideas of how to validate whether the ip address / host name is private or public? the third party website or plugin is acceptable here.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you..

Comment: No. Don't do something like this with clientside JavaScript. You need some serverside logic to protect the "private path" anyway, so do this recognition of local-network clients on the server.

Comment: @Bergi : hmm I am required to do it in client side dear.

Comment: OK, whatever. You've been warned :-) So what's the problem then? Just get `location.host` and test whether it's the public or the private one.

Comment: @Bergi, The problem is, I have no idea about testing it. I don't want to detect it using string of IP address to compare by the ranges.

Comment: Just check whether `location.host == MySite.WebServiceHost`, a simple string comparison? What else would you want to do?

Comment: @Bergi You've saved my day Bergi! Thanks.